# Yii's JUIDatePicker widget not working for updates

Tags: yii, uidatepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm using Yii's **zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDatePicker** and have the following problem:
It works well when inserting a new record, or when updating a record with a NULL date.
But when I try to update a record with a date value, I can't change it.
Do you know what may be happening?

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDatePicker', array(
  'model' => $model,
  'attribute' => 'datetime',
  'name' => $model->datetime,
  'options'=>array(
    'showAnim'=>'fold',
    'dateFormat'=>'yy-mm-dd', 
    'altFormat'=>'yy-mm-dd',
    'changeMonth'=>'true', 
    'changeYear'=>'true', 
    'yearRange'=>'1920:2010', 
    'showOn'=>'both',
    'buttonText'=>'...' ),
  'htmlOptions'=>array( 'style'=>'height:20px;' ),
) );
```

Although the field is named *datetime* it's actually a date MySQL field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming in your update action you have something like this:

```
public function actionUpdate($id){

   $model=$this->loadModel($id);

   // Assuming the name of your model is DateModel
   if(isset($_POST['DateModel'])){
        $model->attributes = $_POST['DateModel'];
        // more code to validate and save
   }
   // more code
}
```

Now, if you check the source of the generated html for your **form view**, you'll see that the **id** and **name** of the input element for your `datetime` attribute is set as the value of that attribute, which actually happens due to the line `'name'=>$model->datetime`. For example it could end up being something like:

```
<input type="text" value="2012-02-08" name="2012-02-08" id="2012-02-08" style="height:20px;" class="hasDatepicker">
```

Whereas what we want is:

```
<input type="text" value="2012-02-08" name="DateModel[datetime]" id="DateModel_datetime" style="height:20px;" class="hasDatepicker">
```

So that our controller action can assign the value of the attributes using the line `$model->attributes = $_POST['DateModel'];` .
Hence a simple solution is **not to use** the `'name'` attribute of the CJuiDatePicker widget.

### Edit:

Otherwise if you absolutely need the 'name' attribute, you have to set the date field in your controller action, like this:

```
$model->attributes = $_POST['DateModel'];
$model->datetime = $_POST[''.$model->datetime];
```

Comment: just remove the `'name'` attribute of the CJuiDatePicker widget.

Comment: Well if you read my post, that wasn't the problem, as the value got to the DB when inserting new records, but thanks anyway.

Comment: hey, that is the issue, i tried it, when inserting new records, the `'name'=>$model->datetime` value is null, as the model has no values yet. But when updating an existing record, $model->datetime will have a value, right? So that value becomes the name and id of the input. I have tested it, please try it and see how it works. I also did read your question properly. All you have to do to try it, is comment the `'name'=>$model->datetime` line.

Comment: It is just that according to the default controller actionUpdate, yii expects all values of a **form** to be in an array like : ModelName[attributeName], but when you change the name it becomes different, and in your case yyyy-mm-dd.

Comment: However if you assign null to name, the default behavior of input widgets takes over and the name becomes ModelName[attributeName]. And that's why it works during insert but not in update.

Comment: Yes, you're right, that was an error indeed, but I already had commented it and it didn't work either. Anyway, I moved to a date/time picker because I needed time also, and just worked at the first try, so didn't had to solve this anyway. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should specify the "value" attribute:

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDatePicker', array(
  'model' => $model,
  'attribute' => 'datetime',
  'value' => $model->datetime,
  ...
```

Comment: Thanks, but the value is being retrieved from the DB correctly (the param *attribute* does it), and in the cases of creation and updating when the datetime value is NULL, it does get written to the DB ok. The problem is on updates when datetime is not NULL.